# Marcar checkbox si hay texto especifico en tabla

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql-server

Buen día
tengo un formulario en el cual tengo diferentes checkbox para mostrar diferentes procesos, en la base de datos los procesos aparecen con un texto "especifico" a veces cambia pero siempre lleva una palabra original por ejemplo "PEGADO" puede ser "PEGADO REVERSO" pero sigue siendo pegado, entonces lo que yo busco hacer es que cuando haga la consulta desde el formulario en base al id que si lleva esa palabra se marque el checkbox correspondiente, les muestro un ejemplo de las tablas..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en el formulario lo tengo de esta manera...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces si al realizar la consulta en base al id y si lleva alguna de esas palabras que tiene alado del checkbox que se marquen los correspondientes..
hasta el momento solo puedo marcarlos con la condicional de que si hay texto se marque pero no diferencia por palabras entonces no puedo hacer que se marque uno en especifico..

```js
if(a3 >= "1"){template.getElementById('sj_a3_1').checked = true}else{template.getElementById('sj_a3_1').checked = false}
```

Comment: Muestra algo más de código, con lo que incluyes, no hay por dónde. Si esto lo haces del lado del cliente, quita la etiqueta PHP y reduce todo a HTML/JavaScript, incluye un ejemplo de como tienes la información del lado del cliente (un const con el json suele ser suficiente). Por otro lado, si lo haces del lado del servidor, quita la etiqueta javascript y muestra algo de código PHP, incluyendo una consulta mínima y los datos que devuelve. En otras palabras, incluye un [mcve] y ajusta bien las etiquetas. Para más información, visita [ask]. Un saludo.